# Best way to iterate array of hashes javascript

Tags: javascript

If i have an array of hashes, whats the best way to iterate?

```
var a = [{"a": "1"}, {"b": "2"}, {"c": "3"}]

for(var i in a) {
  console.log(a[i]) //prints each hash
  console.log(i)    //prints the index
}
```

If i want to get a,b,c or 1,2,3 whats the best way?

Thanks

Comment: you have to break apart the hash with `.keys()` or `.values()`.

Comment: `[{a: "1"}, {b: "2"}, {c: "3"}]` is not valid JavaScript. The variables a, b and c are not initialized. It should be `[{"a": "1"}, {"b": "2"}, {"c": "3"}]`. The second `console.log` is outside of the for-loop, use curly braces `{ ... }`.

Comment: You should never iterate an array with `for (var i in a)` in Javascript because that iterates all enumerable properties of `a` which can include more items than just array elements.

Comment: Sorry, syntax wasnt my point.  Fixed it.  So if i want the keys, `Object.keys(a) returns 0,1,2...`

Comment: Fix your data structure.  It should  probably be: `var a = {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}` and then you can just get the keys with `Object.keys(a)` and then get any value with `a[key]`.

Comment: @jfriend00, i still dont understand.  If i run `Object.keys(a)` i get `0,1,2`

Comment: @AxelAmthor: `[{a: "1"}, {b: "2"}, {c: "3"}]` is very valid JavaScript. The keys in an object literal can be identifier names, strings or numbers.

Comment: Did you really change the structure to what @jfriend00 proposed? I doubt it.

Comment: If you do what I suggested, you will get `["a","b","c"]` for the keys.  See here for working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dt7Le6h9/

Comment: @FelixKling try with IE < 9 and be surprised ....

Comment: @AxelAmthor: I can run `var a = [{a: 42}]; alert(a[0].a);` in **IE6** without any problems. But even if it didn't work, it doesn't change the fact that you claimed that some valid JS is invalid.

Comment: @FelixKling as per definition, property names have to be in double quotes. "Works" is not "Valid". I didn't find any definition, where a literal `a` as a property is explicitly allowed, but always `"a"`. Try `var a = { unknownprop: "value" }` and google for "JSON Syntax Definition"

Comment: @AxelAmthor: Oh, you are confusing [JSON](http://json.org/) with [JavaScript object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals)! They look similar but have different syntax (for example, JSON doesn't have any syntax for functions). Let me refer you to the [*JavaScript specification*](https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5). As you can see, a `PropertyName` can either be a `IdentifierName` (e.g. `foo`), a `StringLiteral` (e.g. `'foo'` or `"foo"`) or a `NumericLiteral` (e.g. `42`).

Comment: @AxelAmthor: `{ unknownprop: "value" }` would be invalid JSON, but is a valid JS object literal. And yes, in this context, "works" means "valid" for me, because "invalid" JavaScript would throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
var a = [{
    "a": "1"
}, {
    "b": "2"
}, {
    "c": "3"
}]
var keys = [];
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var key in a[i]) {
        if (a[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keys.push(key);
            values.push(a[i][key]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

It will iterate through your array and for each object, iterate through it's keys and push the keys and values into separate arrays.

Answer (score 2):

There's the for-of loop proposed in ECMAScript 6.

```
for (obj of a){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj) // if you don't know the keys
    var value = obj[keys[0]] //in case your object has only one key
}
```

This feature appeared in Firefox 31 and it is shipped with Chrome 38. IE doesn't implement it. Don't know about other browsers.

Alternatively,

```
a.forEach(function(obj){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj) // if you don't know the keys
    var value = obj[keys[0]] //in case your object has only one key
});
```

Comment: So for use in IE, is there another way?